# grouping options problem in `pgfplots.groupplots` when also using `units` library

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a problem with the grouping options of `pgfplots.groupplots`. Besides the labels I have also `units` defined. With the option `xlabels at=edge bottom` only the label, but not the unit is moved to the bottom of the group (same with `ylabels`).

```
\pgfplotsset{
    use units,
    x unit=s, x unit prefix={}, % 5.3.1 p227
    y unit=\unitfrac{rad}{s}, y unit prefix={},
    xlabel=time,
    ylabel=frequency $\omega$,
}

\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
     group name=my plots,
        group size=2 by 2,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        ylabels at=edge left,
    },
```

Any ideas how to put also the unit to the bottom?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved by updating PGFPlots to v1.14

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit: Simple solution:** If you just need to get this working and don't want to fiddle with the library code, you can just switch off the units for individual plots by using `\nextgroupplot [x unit={}]` or `y unit={}` or both, depending on which plot is next.

**"Proper" Solution:**
It seems like these two libraries are just not aware of each other, so you'll have to make some adjustments to the `groupplots` code. The labels are set right in the main chunk of code, unfortunately, so you can't get away with just redefining some small macros.

In the file `tikzlibrarypgfplots.groupplots.code.tex` you have to replace the two occurrences of the line

```
\pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@row/.append style={/pgfplots/xlabel={}}}%
```

with

```
\pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@row/.append style={/pgfplots/xlabel={}}%
\ifpgfplots@units@use
  \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@row/.append style={/pgfplots/x unit={}}
\fi}%
```

and the two occurrences of the line

```
\pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@row/.append style={/pgfplots/ylabel={}}}%
```

with

```
\pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@row/.append style={/pgfplots/ylabel={}}%
\ifpgfplots@units@use
  \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@row/.append style={/pgfplots/y unit={}}
\fi}%
```

This will work with or without the `units` library, and with all combinations of `edge bottom`, `edge top`, `edge left`, and `edge right`.

Here's an example of the behaviour of the modified library:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,units}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{
    use units,
    x unit=s, x unit prefix={}, % 5.3.1 p227
    y unit=m, y unit prefix=k,
    xlabel=time,
    ylabel=frequency $\omega$,
}

\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
     group name=my plots,
        group size=2 by 2,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        ylabels at=edge left
    },height=4cm, width=4cm]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (1,0)};
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplots with units and patched groupplots library]

Comment: if you use the units also for scaling i thing the first 'simple' workaround doesn't help (then you could also ignore units and put the unit in math mode into your label). the 'proper' solution works fine although i hoped it would be easier. but thanks!

Comment: thanks for the hack! Could this be patched into the pgfplots package?

Comment: in TeX Live 2014, the two lines you refer to don't exist anymore. How can the problem be fixed there? (interestingly, the problem occurs only for the y labels, not for the x labels)

Comment: @riddleculous: Sorry, there was an error in my answer, the correct file name is `tikzlibrarypgfplots.groupplots.code.tex`. For getting this incorporated into PGFPlots, you could open a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/)

Comment: @Jake: Thanks! I'll do that as soon as I've handed in my thesis ;-)

Comment: This is not a feature request but a _bug_ which was already reported [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/119/). As always: Jake is the best fixing the bugs ;)  I'll edit the report to point to this fix. Many thanks for that!

Comment: Thanks for the reports and thanks for the fix! It is now part of pgfplots (will become part of pgfplots 1.14).